# Reactive Extensions Load / Save linq expressions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've used reactive extensions to a good deal of success.... statically defining criteria in .Where(), and of the more simple criteria and aggregations.

What I'd like to be able to do is allow some configurability for users at runtime. I'm failing to come up with a great way to do this... but had a few ideas... Im soliciting other ways to do this..

Since it doesnt seem like I'll be able to really have a user via a web app define a real linq expression... I'm assuming I'll need to build some sort of complex criteria object that I can serialize to/from disk, and translate to that linq at startup time.

Is there a better way to do this, or are there projects that expand on RX like that as is?

Comment: Please post your ideas. That'll give us a foundation to work from.

Comment: There are some interesting videos on Microsoft's Channel 9 about how Rx is used to power Cortana. Apparently they extended the Rx objects to include serialization.

Comment: So I found reference to a Channel9 discussion with Bart de Smet regarding how rx was used in Cortana... this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for... except that there didnt appear to be enough details to actually build any projects myself. https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-Rx-and-Cortana

Comment: Yes, it is a bit sad that they haven't released those bits. Presumably they are rock solid. Maybe it's because they are only a subset of the entire Rx code base.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely, you can use System.Linq.Dynamic nuget package to achieve that for example:

```
  var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(long), "t");
  var lambda = (Func<long,bool>)System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression
  .ParseLambda( new[] { p }, typeof(bool),"t % 2 == 0").Compile();    
  var subs = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Where(lambda);
```

In above code you can persist the string that's in the filter and reload it as you like.